# In Playframework2, how can I use "specs2-scalacheck"?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, specs2, scalacheck

I want to use ScalaCheck with specs2 in Playframework 2.3.x, and write like this in `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ...
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-scalacheck" % "2.11.5",
  ...)
```

However, I found this will return an error during compiling

```
[info] Resolving org.specs2#specs2-scalacheck_2.11;2.11.5 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.specs2#specs2-scalacheck_2.11;2.11.5
```

I thought the version of `specs2-scalacheck` may be incompatible with the `org.specs2` dependencies in Playframework. However, I don't know the exact version of `specs2` in Playframework, which exists in neither `build.sbt` nor `plugin.sbt`.

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `specs2-scalacheck` version should be something that is published [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/specs2/specs2-scalacheck_2.11/). For example `2.4.17`.